# Image pop out "right-to-left" with storyboard animation

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, animation

I found a good example for a pop out image: http://tozon.info/blog/post/2007/10/14/three-ways-to-make-your-wpf-images-pop-out-on-mouseover.aspx

the problem is I need to grow it in the opposite direction. The image in the example grows from left to right. I want it to grow to the left side.

```
<!-- This storyboard will make the image grow to double its size in 0.2 seconds -->
<Storyboard x:Key="expandStoryboard">
  <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleX"
                   To="2"
                   Duration="0:0:0.2" />
  <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleY"
                   To="2"
                   Duration="0:0:0.2" />
</Storyboard>
<!-- This storyboard will make the image revert to its original size -->
<Storyboard x:Key="shrinkStoryboard">
  <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleX"
                   To="1"
                   Duration="0:0:0.2" />
  <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleY"
                   To="1"
                   Duration="0:0:0.2" />
</Storyboard>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`RenderTransformOrigin`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.rendertransformorigin.aspx) to make the image pop out from right-to-left by defining the origin as `new Point(1,0.5)` in code behind, or `<Image ... RenderTransformOrigin="1,0.5" />` in XAML. You may want to use `1` instead of `0.5` for the *yOrigin* if you want the image to scale out from the bottom right corner.

Comment: Great! I made it with RenderTransformOrigin="1,0". So it scale out from the top right corner